# Найти самую длинную непрерывную последовательность из нулей в записи чисел от L до R в системе счисления с основанием K

Tags: c++, c

Найти самую длинную непрерывную последовательность из нулей в записи чисел от L до R в системе счисления с основанием K.
Пример: L=10, R=20, K=2 Ответ: 4. Ограничения - 0<=L,R<=10^18

Есть идеи у кого?

С уважением,

Александр

Comment: Что именно не получается? Разложить число на цифры в нужной системе счисления?

Comment: Мне только кажется или в любой системе счисления это будет (длинна R)-1, где R записано в нужной СИ

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну, я не думаю что для 10^18 это целесообразно - да и очень долго. Ограничения-то не на 100

Comment: Чутка ошибся, Длинна(R-L)-1....

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, к примеру: L=1024, R=1024, а нулей-то 10.

Comment: @СашаНовожилов нулей вообщето в вашем примере всего 1(или СИ указать забыли) =) и да, не выйдет так просто, согласен =)

Comment: Вы пологаете наличие математического решения задачи или алгоритмического?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков хотелось бы решение алгоритмическое

Comment: Наибольшая степень K со значением между L и R, если нет, то ближайшая к L снизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Переводим `l` и `r` в заданную систему счисления
2. Если числа имеют разную длину, ответ - длина `r` минус 1
3. Находим максимально число идущих подряд нулей в `l`
4. Если `l==r` заканичваем с ответом с шага 3
5. Откусываем от чисел общий префикс и ещё один символ
6. Выбираем максимум из числа с шага 3 и длины хвоста с шага 5

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85417/discussion-between-qwertiy-and--).